# Learning assembly - did I count the output correctly of this short assembler code?

Tags: assembly, x86

Given an assembly `x86` code.. `x` is a memory address. Value `3` is included in this address at the beginning. `sal` shifts the binary number in the register `n` bits to the left.

```
mov ax, [x]
sal ax, 3
add ax, [x]
sal ax, 1
mov [z], ax
```

So first line we `move` `[x]` which includes `3` to `ax`.

Second line we take what is in `ax` and `shift` it by `3` to the left. `3` in binary is `011`, so here we got `011000` which is `24` in decimal.

Third line we `add` what is in `[x]` with `ax`, so `24 + 3 = 27`

Fourth line: `27` in binary is `011011`, we `shift` this to left by `1`, so we got `0110110` which is `54` in decimal.

Last line we take what is in `ax` and put it / save it into memory `z`

So in the end `[z] = 54`.

---

This was a task from an old exam. I hope I did it right? I'm especially not sure if I did the shift correctly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: did you try executing this code? that's the easiest way to check whether you got it right. inb4 "stackoverflow is not a CPU"

Comment: I haven't. Started learning assembly yesterday night :D
What would you recommend me to use? I'm a Windows user and so far only played with eclipse (for java)!

Comment: i've only ever used inline assemblers and debuggers, so maybe someone else can suggest a good assembler for beginners

Comment: That said, allow me to show you how convenient inline assembly is in the D language — https://dpaste.dzfl.pl/5eb10c884050

Comment: Also, you might as well close this question since it's not really appropriate for stackoverflow; it's more of a code-review question, and i think by having an assembler you can test your code with, the 'root' of your problem is solved.

Comment: what you calculated was [z]  = ( [x]*8+[x] ) *2 = [x] * 18

Comment: Thank you guys! :) Understood

Comment: Yes, you did everything right in your example. One thing: *"Value 3 is included in this address"* - it's handy to specify value size, so you know how many bytes of memory are affected, ie think about "word value 3", and memory "contains" the value (include sounds weird to me in this context). You can use NASM as assembler, it's capable to compile 16, 32 and 64b code, and it's available for many platforms. More difficult question is how to *see* your code, a good debugger is a must. I'm not sure what to suggest for windows, check SO x86 tag documentation, or maybe thing like http://x64dbg.com/

Comment: Ped7g is absolutely right, having a solid debugger is invaluable when writing assembly. x64dbg is good, and OllyDbg is the most user-friendly for 32-bit code. It will take some time to learn how to use them if you're new to assembly though.